# How to print a range of elements of std::vector in lldb?

Tags: lldb

How do I print in lldb the entries in a std::vector between say 1000 - 1073.

For example in the following code:

```
   1
   2    #include <numeric>
   3    #include <vector>
   4
   5    using namespace std;
   6
   7    int main() {
   8      vector<int> v(100000);
   9      std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
-> 10     return 0;
   11   }
(lldb)
```

I want to see what is in v[1000] - v[1073]

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a subrange operator in the lldb variable printing.  But you can do this sort of thing pretty simply with the Python API's.  For instance:

```
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> for i in range(2,6):
...     print(lldb.frame.GetValueForVariablePath("int_vec[%d]"%(i)))
... 
(int) [2] = 3
(int) [3] = 4
(int) [4] = 5
(int) [5] = 6
```

You could make up a little command to do this easily as well. See:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#create-a-new-lldb-command-using-a-python-function

for details on doing that, and:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/index.html

for a general reference to the Python API's.